# Binomial confidence intervals and the Central Limit Theorem

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, central-limit-theorem

Suppose I want to estimate the head probability p for a biased coin. Usually this is done by assuming the distribution tends to normal using large number of trials and CLT. I am wondering how robust is the CLT approximation. Because confidence interval is an objective statement about the true value of p, would CLT approximation makes the confidence interval calculated this way wrong in some extreme cases?  Also, How to find the confidence interval for this simple coin flip example exactly without using CLT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have $x = 21$ successes in $n = 50$ trials. Here are a few
approaches to getting a 95% CI for success probability $\theta.$

**Using binomial tails in quest of an "exact" interval.** Without using a normal approximation, the rough idea to get a 95% CI for binomial success probability $\theta$
is to find $\theta_1$ such that $P(X \le x; n, \theta_1) \approx .025$
and $\theta_2$ such that $P(X \le x; n, \theta_2) \approx .975.$ Then
the CI is $(\theta_1, \theta_2).$
This idea is discussed in Section 3 of [*these course notes*](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~ramsey/TraditionalBinomialCI.pdf).

Briefly, an important difficulty is that the discreteness of the binomial distribution
prevents getting 'tail probabilities' of exactly .025 for either $\theta_i.$
One solution is to fuss about putting a little more probability in one tail
and a little less in the other tail in order to get as close to a 95% CI
as possible. Another solution (the 'conservative approach') is to allow tail probabilities smaller than .025
to ensure at least 95% confidence

Below is a rough demonstration (with no fussing) that I programmed in R statistical
software. It gives the CI $(.300, .568).$

```
x = 21;  n = 50
th = seq(0, 1, by=.001)        # grid of values of 'theta' in [0,1]
cdf = pbinom(x, n, th)
d1 = abs(cdf - .975)
th1 = th[d1 == min(d1)];  th1
## 0.3
d2 = abs(cdf - .025)
th2 = th[dl == min(dl)];  th2
## 0.568
```

In R, a refined version of this style of CI is part of the output of the function `binom.test`, which includes the CI $(0.282, 0.568).$  From what I can tell,
this function uses a conservative approach, hence the slightly smaller
left endpoint. [By default, the function tests whether the coin is fair, although other hypotheses may be specified.]

```
binom.test(21,50)

        Exact binomial test

data:  21 and 50
number of successes = 21, number of trials = 50, p-value = 0.3222
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.2818822 0.5679396
sample estimates:
probability of success 
                  0.42
```

**Bayesian Posterior Interval.** Sometimes Bayesian posterior intervals
are used as confidence intervals. Based on a 'noninformative' $\mathsf{Unif}(0,1)$ prior distribution and the binomial likelihood function from
$x = 21$ and $n = 50$, one obtains the posterior distribution
$\mathsf{Beta}(x + 1, n-x + 1).$ Cutting probability .025 from each tail
of this distribution one obtains the interval $(0.293, 0.558).$

```
qbeta(c(.025,.975), x+1,n-x+1)
## 0.2934549 0.5583072
```

**Agresti-Coull Interval.** The so-called 'Wald'
CI, based on $\hat \theta  = x/n,$ is of the form $\hat \theta \pm 1.96\sqrt{\hat\theta(1-\hat\theta)/n}.$  You are correct that this
kind of interval can give very bad results for small $n,$ especially
when $\theta$ is far from $1/2.$ Not only does it use a normal
approximation that may not be appropriate for such $n$ and $\theta,$ it
also assumes (under the square root sign) that $\hat\theta = s/n$ is
the same as $\theta.$ "Bad" means
that the true coverage probability of a 
"95%" CI can be far from $95\%$, often much lower.

However, a considerable improvement is achieved by using
$\tilde n = n + 4$ and $\tilde\theta = (x+2)/\tilde n$ to make the CI
$\tilde \theta \pm 1.96\sqrt{\tilde\theta(1-\tilde\theta)/\tilde n}.$ 
This is called the Agresti-Coull interval; for confidence levels other
than 95%, slight adjustments are made. You can google 'Agresti interval'
for details. The Agresti interval for $x = 21$ and $n = 50$ is $(0.294, 0.558)$.

```
pa = (x+2)/(n+4);  pm = -1:1
pa + pm*1.96*sqrt(pa*(1-pa)/(n+4))
## 0.2940364 0.4259259 0.5578154
```

While the Agresti intervals use a normal approximation, they do not
assume that $\tilde \theta$ is the same as $\theta.$

When $n$ is quite small, all of the CIs based on a normal approximation
perform badly. However, when $n$ is small it is increasingly difficult
to find appropriate binomial quantiles to make an "exact" interval of approximate
confidence 95% (or any other desired level).

Comment: In the discrete setting I am inclined to just report the interval at whatever level of significance it provides, rather than seeking out the interval for a specified level of significance. This is basically your "conservative" approach, except that in doing this you could also *reduce* the level of significance from your initial "target".

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer. One thing to clarify: when you say " this kind of interval can give very bad results for small n, especially when θ is far from 1/2", why does it give bad result for θ far from 1/2? Is it because of the truncation?

Comment: @user3229471 Normal approximation is valid for $nq \gg 1$ where $q=\min \{ p,1-p \}$.

Comment: Is it possible then to use the truncated normal? @lan

Comment: @user3229471 I do not know whether there is a way to use some sort of asymmetrically truncated normal distribution for that purpose.

Comment: @Ian. [_One of my previous answers_](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1774396/is-a-90-confidence-interval-really-90-confident/1774550#1774550) on binomial CIs shows the poor 'coverage' probability of the Wald Interval, even in cases where the usual rules of thumb for using normal aprx to binom are satisfied. Lack of normal fit, discreteness of binomial, and using and estimate for the variance all play roles. Wilson style intervals as well as (above) Agresti, and Bayesian intervals can help. Even AP stat books now suggest Agresti. Flat prior Bayesian is better if software available.

Comment: @BruceET How do we generalize it to the multinomial case(with the contrainst that $\sum \theta_i =1$)? It certainly can be decomposed into several binomial cases, but maybe more exact and tight condition can be given?