# 90% Confidence Interval for Population Proportion Given p' and n

Tags: statistics, binomial-distribution, confidence-interval

I am trying to figure out why, for finding confidence intervals, we use the following standard error

$$SE = \sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}$$

in the formula

$$ \overline{X} \pm z_{(\alpha / 2)} \times SE$$

For the past week I have been cramming into my head that for confidence intervals  of $100(1-\alpha)\%$ we use the following formula

$$ \overline{X} \pm z_{(\alpha / 2)}\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}~~~ \therefore ~~~  SE = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$$

From looking at the answer from [this derivation of SE for Binomials](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/29644/191234) my assumption is that $k = n~~ \therefore ~~\sigma_{\overline{X}} = \sqrt{p(1-p)}$

How would one infer $k = n$ from the following question?

> For a 90% confidence interval for the population proportion, p, if the sample proportion, p', is 0.4 and the sample size is n = 100 then the error term, E, is ______ (to the nearest 0.001).

Comment: There is the distinction between the standard deviation $\sigma$ of a *population* and the standard deviation of a *sample mean* of size $n$ drawn from the (larger) population.  I suspect that is the issue which is confusing you, but I'm not sure exactly what question you've formulated.  The conclusion $k=n$ is tied to the sample size being $n$.

Comment: Lots of previous Q&A's on this site dealing with this topic ([including this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1774396/is-a-90-confidence-interval-really-90-confident/1774550#1774550)). Also other sites. There are several styles of CI for binomial $p.$ I think the one you're being asked to use is $p' \pm 1.645\sqrt{\frac{p'(1-p')}{n}}.$ Look for this formula in your text or notes. This is the most commonly used style of CI, but (according to link earlier) not the best.

Comment: $SD(p') = SD(X/n) = \sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}},$ where $X$ is nr Successes in $n$ trials, and $p$ is population proportion. Because $SD(p')$ involves unknown $p,$ it is necessary to estimate $SD(p')$ when making the CI.  The estimate is $\sqrt{\frac{p'(1-p')}{n}},$ with $p'$ used instead of unknown $p.$ This CI assumes binomial $X$ has nearly a normal distribution.